# Linear congruence with Fermat's little theorem 987x ≡ 610 (mod 1597)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

987x ≡ 610 (mod 1597)

Is this correct way of applying little Fermat's theorem for linear congruences? Does it make any sense? If not could someone advice a bit.

Since gcd(987,1597)=1

-> 987ˆ1597-1 ≡ 1 (mod 1597)

-> 987ˆ1596 ≡ 1 (mod 1597)

```
610 ≡ 610 (1597)

987ˆ1596 * 610 ≡ 610 (mod 1597)

987 * 987ˆ1595 * 610 ≡ 610 (mod 1597)

-> x0 = 987ˆ1595 * 610

->[987ˆ1595 * 610]127
```

Comment: your solution $$x=987$$ is right

Comment: Since $\gcd(987,1597) =1$ then $987^{\phi(1597)} \equiv 1 \mod 1597$.  Is 1597 prime?  If so then $\phi(1597) = 1597-1$ and the result is true.  If $1597$ is composite than that is not true.

Comment: You want $x$ so that
\begin{eqnarray*}
987x=610+1597j
\end{eqnarray*}
So do Euclid's algorithm on $987$ and $1597$.

Comment: If you notice that $987+610=1597$, $x=-1$ or $x=1596$ is the solution.

Comment: Those are all Fibonacci numbers!

Comment: I find it hard to imagine where $987^{1595}*610$ would be considered an acceptable answer if "the number $x$ where $987*x \equiv 610 \mod 1597$" wouldn't be.  As $\gcd(987,1597)=1$ then we know $k$ so that $987k \equiv 1$ exists and so $x = 610*k = 610*987^{-1}$ exists.  But in no sense of the word "find" or "solve" do I think we have done either (Although we could argue that there is no good reason we *should*).

Comment: I can't really read the post but going off fleabood's comment above, you can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find $987^{-1}$ and solve for $x$ explicitly.

Comment: There is a trivial solution: $$x\equiv -1\pmod{1597}.$$

Comment: The post was legit so far as it went.  $987^{1596} \equiv 1 \mod 1597$ so $987 * (987^{1596}*610) \equiv 610 \mod 1597$ so $x \equiv  987^{1596}*610 \mod 1597$.  Which is ... true.  But, it obeys the letter not the spirit of the law.  It think we can and should intepret the question to mean which residue class, [0] to [1596] is $x$ equivalent to.  Which ... this observation does not help with.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio D'oh!  $987 + 610 = 1597$.... D'oh!  Well, we could have still discovered that with Euclids algorithm:  $1597 = k*987 + r; k = 1;r =610$ so $610 = 1597 - 987$ so $x \equiv -1 \mod 1597$.

Answer (score 1):

For an *explicit* solution, you have to perform the *extended Euclidean algorithm*:
$$\begin{array}{rrrc}
& u_i&v_i&q_i \\
\hline
1597& 0&1 \\
987&1&0&1 \\
\hline
610&-1&1&1 \\
377&2&-1&1\\
233&-3&2&1\\
144&5&-3&1\\
89&-8&5&1\\
55&13&-8&1\\
34&-21&13&1\\
21&34&-21&1\\
13&-55&34&1\\
8&89&-55&1\\
5&-144&89&1\\
3&233&-144&1\\
2&-377&233&1 \\
1&\color{red}{610}&-377\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Hence, a *Bézout's relation* between $987$ and $1597$ is $\;610\cdot 987-377\cdot 1597=1$, which shows that
$$987^{-1}\bmod 1597=610, \quad \text{whence }\; x\equiv 610^2\equiv \color{red}{-1\bmod1597}.$$

Comment: $377-233=144{}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Thanks for pointing the error! I'll fix it.

Comment: That can't be right because 1) $52*987 = 51324 \equiv 220 \mod 1597$ and 1) $610 + 987 = 1597$ so $987 \equiv -610$ so $x \equiv -1$ is a solution and as $1597$ is prime is a unique solution.

Comment: Although Euclid agorithm will always get us to $\gcd(a,b)$ but if you are trying to solve $ak + bj = m\gcd(a,b)$ and you get a remainder of $m\gcd(a,b)$ along the way, you don't *need* to go all the way to $\gcd(a,b)$ and multiply by $m$.  You are already done.  $1597 - 987 = 610$.  Stop!  You are done!

Comment: Sure, if I already know what the g.c.d. is. Also, my point was to illustrate the general method.

Comment: As I said in an earlier comment, every number in the problem is a Fibonacci number. I am sure you now appreciate that consecutive Fibonacci numbers are a "worst case" for the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Absolutely. I didn't know this fact, but the number of properties of Fibonacci numbers is fascinating: I suppose you know there's a proof of the infiniteness of prime numbers  based on Fibonacci numbers?.

Answer (score 1):

I like to do the extended Euclidean algorithm by continued fractions.

$$  \gcd( 1597, 987 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 1597 }{ 987 } = 1 +  \frac{ 610 }{ 987 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 987 }{ 610 } = 1 +  \frac{ 377 }{ 610 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 610 }{ 377 } = 1 +  \frac{ 233 }{ 377 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 377 }{ 233 } = 1 +  \frac{ 144 }{ 233 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 233 }{ 144 } = 1 +  \frac{ 89 }{ 144 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 144 }{ 89 } = 1 +  \frac{ 55 }{ 89 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 89 }{ 55 } = 1 +  \frac{ 34 }{ 55 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 55 }{ 34 } = 1 +  \frac{ 21 }{ 34 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 34 }{ 21 } = 1 +  \frac{ 13 }{ 21 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 21 }{ 13 } = 1 +  \frac{ 8 }{ 13 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 13 }{ 8 } = 1 +  \frac{ 5 }{ 8 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 8 }{ 5 } = 1 +  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 5 }{ 3 } = 1 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 3 }{ 2 } = 1 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 8 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 13 }{ 8 }   & &   \frac{ 21 }{ 13 }   & &   \frac{ 34 }{ 21 }   & &   \frac{ 55 }{ 34 }   & &   \frac{ 89 }{ 55 }   & &   \frac{ 144 }{ 89 }   & &   \frac{ 233 }{ 144 }   & &   \frac{ 377 }{ 233 }   & &   \frac{ 610 }{ 377 }   & &   \frac{ 1597 }{ 987 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 8 }{ 5 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 13 }{ 8 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 21 }{ 13 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 34 }{ 21 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 55 }{ 34 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 89 }{ 55 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 144 }{ 89 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 233 }{ 144 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 377 }{ 233 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 610 }{ 377 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 1597 }{ 987 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  0  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 1597 \cdot 377 - 987 \cdot 610 = -1 $$

I guess they did this on purpose, it turns out
$$ 987 \cdot 610 \equiv 1 \pmod {1597}. $$ With
$$ 987 \cdot x \equiv 610 \pmod {1597}, $$ we get
$$ x \equiv 610^2 \pmod {1597}, $$
 $$ x \equiv 1596 \equiv -1 \pmod {1597}. $$

I see what happened, $610 + 987 = 1597,$ so $x\equiv -1$ makes sense.  Altogether, the square rrots of $-1$ are $610$ and $987.$ Well, why not?